# Flutter Horizontal ListView.builder() not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm making an API call, which gives back a `list`. I want to display, let's say, `SomeWidget()` horizontally using `ListView.builder()`. But I'm not able to achieve that target still.

I've tried wrapping the `ListView.builder()` inside a `Container()` and gave it some height and width. But hard luck. I've also tried wrapping it using `Expanded()`. But hard luck. I have tried wrapping it with, first a `Container()` then wrapping the `Container()` with `Expanded()`. Still hard luck.

The error that I keep getting is the following:

```
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
```

Here's my `ListView.builder()` code:

```
someList.isNotEmpty ? 
  Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
   child: Column(
   children: [
   Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
    child: Text('HEADING',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
   ),
    ),
       ),
        Container(
           height: 15.h,
           width: 80.w,
           child: ListView.builder(
           scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
           itemCount: someList.length,
           itemBuilder: (_, index) {
           return SomeWidget();
          }),
         ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   ) : Text(''),
```

Is there any other information that I should add here?

**Update**
The ListView.builder() is working perfectly for vertical scrolling. The code is the following:

```
Container(
   height: 15.h,
   width: double.infinity,
   child: ListView.builder(
   // scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   itemCount: someList.length,
   itemBuilder: (_, index) {
   return SomeWidget();
   },
  ),
),
```

On adding `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`, it however doesn't work.

Comment: I think the causing widget is one of the parents. Can you share the whole code from the scaffold?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Add Your **ListView.builder()** inside **Expanded or Flex** Widget hope its help to you

```
Column(
     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
     children: <Widget>[
     Expanded(
      child:ListView.builder(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       itemCount: someList.length,
       itemBuilder: (_, index) {
           return SomeWidget();
     }),
    ),
   ],
  ),
```

Comment: I've added Expanded() but hard luck.

Comment: let me know what exactly should I add please.

Comment: you have used Column Wigtet?

Comment: yes. it's inside a Column() because I've a heading for the horizontal list.

Comment: use mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, inside column ,see my updated answer

Comment: I found this solution in one of the questions in this platform. And tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Container(
    //Try add height and width
   child: Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   textDirection : TextDirection.ltr or rtl
   children: [
   Align(
    Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    horizontal: 12, vertical: 6),
    child: Text('HEADING',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
   ),
       ),
```

i think or maybe the listview not the problem maybe inside on the listview item is the problem which as the error you've shown is that need has szie so in between in those item need to be wrap container or sized box

Comment: I've tried this approach too. But I'm getting the same error.

Comment: can u change the code above the whole state starting in scaffold till end

Comment: If I use the widget that I want to display inside listview, without the listview, then it works

Answer (score 0):

If `Expanded` or `Flexible` widgets didn't work, try giving a fixed **width** to your `ListView` items.

```
Column(
     children: [
      child:ListView.builder(
       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
       itemCount: someList.length,
       itemBuilder: (_, index) {
           return Container(width: 150, child: someWidget());
     }),
    ),
   ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

- If the horizontal ListView is in a Column make sure it is in a SizedBox with fixed height.
- Does the ListView item have an Expanded widget inside it? If so make sure the parent of the ListView item is a SizedBox with a fixed width.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: const [
                          Expanded(child: Text('scrollable')),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

hardcoding the height of horizontal ListView.builder would be unpredictable for some cases.

below is horizontal ListView.builder that resize the height itself based on first child

usage:

```
SelfSizedHorizontalList(
  childBuilder: (i) => itemWidget(list[i]),
  itemCount: list.length,
),
```

source code:

```
class SelfSizedHorizontalList extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(int) childBuilder;
  final int itemCount;
  final double gapSize;
  const SelfSizedHorizontalList({
    super.key,
    required this.childBuilder,
    required this.itemCount,
    this.gapSize = 8,
  });

  @override
  State<SelfSizedHorizontalList> createState() => _SelfSizedHorizontalListState();
}

class _SelfSizedHorizontalListState extends State<SelfSizedHorizontalList> {
  final infoKey = GlobalKey();

  double? prevHeight;
  double? get height {
    if (prevHeight != null) return prevHeight;
    prevHeight = infoKey.globalPaintBounds?.height;
    return prevHeight;
  }

  bool get isInit => height == null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (height == null) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((v) => setState(() {}));
    }
    if (widget.itemCount == 0) return const SizedBox();
    if (isInit) return Container(key: infoKey, child: widget.childBuilder(1));
    return SizedBox(
      height: height,
      child: ListView.separated(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: widget.itemCount,
        itemBuilder: (c, i) => widget.childBuilder.call(i),
        separatorBuilder: (c, i) => SizedBox(width: widget.gapSize),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension GlobalKeyExtension on GlobalKey {
  Rect? get globalPaintBounds {
    final renderObject = currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    final translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null).getTranslation();
    if (translation != null && renderObject?.paintBounds != null) {
      final offset = Offset(translation.x, translation.y);
      return renderObject!.paintBounds.shift(offset);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```